# Android Unable to register Appium to selenium grid on windows

Tags: appium, selenium-grid

I am trying to register Appium to local Selenium grid. Below are my steps:

1. I am able to access grid console at

> http://localhost:4444/grid/console

2. I created below configuration json file:-

> { "capabilities": [{ "browserName": "Android", "version": "4.4.2",
>   "maxInstances": 1, "platform": "Android", "deviceName":
>   "4d0002174dca3161", }], "configurations": { "cleanUpCycle": 2000,
>   "timeout": 30000, "proxy":
>   "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy", "host":
>   "127.0.0.1", "port": 4723, "url": "http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub",
>   "maxSession": 1, "register": true, "registerCycle": 5000, "hubPort":
>   4444, "hubHost": "127.0.0.1", "hub":
>   "http://127.0.0.1:4444/grid/register" } }

The deviceName is from:

> "adb devices" command

3. When I started Appium with command

> appium --nodeconfig C:\mobile\androidConfig.json

I am getting an exception:

> info: Welcome to Appium v1.3.4 (REV
>   c8c79a85fbd6870cd6fc3d66d038a115ebe22efe) info: Appium REST http
>   interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723 info: [debug] Non-default
>   server args: {"nodeconfig":"C:\mobile\androidConfig. json"} info:
>   Console LogLevel: debug error: uncaughtException: Cannot read property
>   'url' of undefined date=Tue Feb 1 0 2015 15:08:52 GMT+0200 (South
>   Africa Standard Time), pid=8644, uid=null, gid=n ull,
>   cwd=C:\Users\administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium,
>   execPath=C:\Pr ogram Files\nodejs\node.exe, version=v0.10.30,
>   argv=[node, C:\Users\administrator\AppDa
>   ta\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\bin\appium.js, -p, 4723,
>   --nodeconfig, C:\mob ile\androidConfig.json], rss=45649920, heapTotal=35002496, heapUsed=23290972, lo adavg=[0, 0, 0],
>   uptime=11049.0117945, trace=[column=32, file=C:\Users\administrator\Ap
>   pData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\lib\server\grid-register.js,
>   function=post Request, line=46, method=null, native=false, column=7,
>   file=C:\Users\administrator\AppD
>   ata\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\lib\server\grid-register.js,
>   function=null, line=14, method=null, native=false, column=14,
>   file=fs.js, function=null, line=2 71, method=null, native=false,
>   column=15, file=fs.js, function=Object.oncomplete , line=107,
>   method=oncomplete, native=false], stack=[TypeError: Cannot read prop
>   erty 'url' of undefined, at postRequest
>   (C:\Users\administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm
>   \node_modules\appium\lib\server\grid-register.js:46:32), at
>   C:\Users\administrator\
>   AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\lib\server\grid-register.js:14:7,
>   at fs.js:271:14, at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, It was a silly typo.

“configurations” node was incorrectly written. It should be configuration “without an s”. In addition, on the platform side, it should be MAC or WINDOWS

node got successfully registered to the Grid after above changes.